# Comparing Dates in a specific format in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column called "Mon-YY" (varchar(n) data type) in one of my tables which has values like:

Aug-12

Sep-12

Oct-12

Nov-12

Dec-12

Jan-13

Feb-13

Mar-13

Apr-13

May-13

Jun-13

I want to compare these values and retrieve the records from the table based on the date range specified.

I am assuming I'd need to convert the above values into DATE format. But I'm not sure then how do I keep track of days too.

Comment: Why do you not store datetime data in a datetime datatype? Yes to use this information you are going to have to manipulate this so you can turn them into actual datatime values. Not sure what you mean about keeping track of days though.

Comment: It's because of the reporting constraints. I need to select the dates in this(Year and Month) from the UI and then run the query based on that.

Comment: So store your datetime data as datetime. Reporting is not a reason to use an incorrect datatype. Build that type of conversion stuff into your code, not make your database harder to work with.

Answer (score 0):

To convert these values to date you should use:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), '01 ' + [Mon-YY], 6) as BeginOfInterval
```

To get the last day of a month, you should use ([look here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/08/18/sql-server-find-last-day-of-any-month-current-previous-next/)):

```
SELECT DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, 
     DATEDIFF(m,0,CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), '01 ' + [Mon-YY], 6))+1,0)) as EndOfInterval
```

Then you could use this two queries to get the first and last dates of interval.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`DATEPART`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) function, but you need to do it on a full date:

```
SELECT DATEPART(MM, 'Aug-12') --> error
SELECT DATEPART(MM', 01-Aug-12') --> 8
```

So try something like this:

```
SELECT
  DATEPART(MM, CONCAT('01-', [Mon-YY])) AS TheMonth,
  DATEPART(YYYY, CONCAT('01-', [Mon-YY])) AS TheYear
FROM myTable
ORDER BY TheYear, TheMonth
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONVERT (date, REPLACE (MyColumn, '-', ' 01 '))
FROM MyTable
```

Something like this should give you a date.  It will always be the first of the month.  You can use the expression in a WHERE clause with <, >, or BETWEEN.  I don't know why you would need to keep track of them.

Answer (score 0):

I used cast

```
-- example table and data
DECLARE  @table table
(
 [Mon-YY] varchar(20)
)


insert into @table values ('Aug-12')
insert into @table values ('Sep-12')
insert into @table values ('Oct-12')
insert into @table values ('Nov-12')
insert into @table values ('Dec-12')
insert into @table values ('Jan-13')
insert into @table values ('Feb-13')
insert into @table values ('Mar-13')
insert into @table values ('Apr-13')
insert into @table values ('May-13')
insert into @table values ('Jun-13')


select cast('01-' + [Mon-YY] as Date)
from @table
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to transform your column in something easier to sort like a number.
Bellow I transform the column in the full year followed by the month (numeric index 1 to 12) but this is used only in order by clause.

```
select  *
from    theTable
--where ???
order by case when right([mon-yy],2) <= 70 then '19' else '20' end +
         right([mon-yy],2) +
         case left([mon-yy],3)
           when 'Jan' then '01'
           when 'Feb' then '02'
           when 'Mar' then '03'
           when 'Apr' then '04'
           when 'May' then '05'
           when 'Jun' then '06'
           when 'Jul' then '07'
           when 'Aug' then '08'
           when 'Sep' then '09'
           when 'Oct' then '10'
           when 'Nov' then '11'
           when 'Dec' then '12'
         end
```